# Sed Replace Around Numeric Content

Tags: sed, replace

I'm modifying an html output

```
<td nowrap align="right">4683</td>
```

I'd like to replace all occurrences in the document matching this pattern, where 4683 may be any given number varying in length

so these lines look like

```
<td nowrap align="right"><a href="4683.html">link</a></td>
```

I think I'm looking for something like this

```
sed -i 's/align="right">/([0-9]*)/<\/td>/align="right"><a href="4683.html">link<\/a><\/td>/g' index.html
```

I understand the Regex may not be included referenced substituted or structured properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about :

```
sed 's_^\([^>]\+>\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)_\1<a href="\2.html">link</a>_' file.txt
```

- We are using `_` in the `sed` substitution pattern format instead `/` as `/` is present in the input
- `^\([^>]\+>\)` finds the characters upto `>` (including) and put them in a group
- `\([[:digit:]]\+\)` finds the mentioned digits and put them in a group so that we can use them later
- The replacement pattern is `\1<a href="\2.html">link</a>` where `\1` is the first matched group and `\2` is the second matched group

  Example :

  ```
  $ sed 's_^\([^>]\+>\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)_\1<a href="\2.html">link</a>_'<<<'<td nowrap align="right">4683</td>'

  <td nowrap align="right"><a href="4683.html">link</a></td>
  ```

If there are no digits elsewhere in the line, then you can simply use :

```
sed 's_[[:digit:]]\+_<a href="&.html">link</a>_' file.txt
```

Example :

```
$ sed 's_[[:digit:]]\+_<a href="&.html">link</a>_'<<<'<td nowrap align="right">4683</td>'

<td nowrap align="right"><a href="4683.html">link</a></td>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but it's also replacing a date field in file.txt. How do I specify this line more independently?

Comment: @user123482 hard to tell without seeing the line..could you give an example..

Comment: The line is <td nowrap align="right">4683</td>. It is the only type of line in the document specifying an align="right" parameter.

Comment: @user123482 Its the same example you have given in your question..its a working one..could you share where this is failing ?

Comment: <td nowrap align="left"><a href="2015.html">link</a>-07-06 12:58</td>
    <td nowrap align="right"><a href="93009.html">link</a></td>       Another line is included in the match

Comment: Problem solved, simply sed 's_^\([^>]\+right">\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)_\1<a href="\2.html">link</a>_' index.html
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
`sed -ri 's/([0-9]+)/<a href=\"&.html\">link<\/a>/g' index.html`